# MYSQL 5.7 status is inactive (dead) in the Ubuntu 18.04 on 64 bits

Tags: 18.04, server, mysql, systemd

While I checking `mysql` status in the ubuntu 18.04 the mysql is inactive. The error of the mysql code is:

```
root@fair-VirtualBox:~# systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service
Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
Active: inactive (dead)

मार्च 11 14:13:00 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:13:34 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:13:34 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:13:34 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:13:34 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:17:20 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
मार्च 11 14:17:20 fair-VirtualBox systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
```

Comment: Can you please add the /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf file? It seems to be a probelm in that file.